# Why is alias not allowed in GROUP BY in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by, alias

I realized that putting an alias in `GROUP BY` and call it in the `SELECT` query is ungrammatical like below.

**ERROR**

```
SELECT 
    day, num
FROM users
GROUP BY DAYNAME(created_at) as day
ORDER BY COUNT(*) as num;
```

However, If I were to do the other way around(using an alias in `SELECT` and then calling it in `GROUP BY`), it works like below.

**CORRECT**

```
SELECT 
    DAYNAME(created_at) as day, COUNT(*) as num
FROM users
GROUP BY day
ORDER BY num;
```

I am aware of the order of execution in MySQL which tells me `SELECT` is executed after `GROUP BY`. but according to the result, it's really confusing to me. Can anyone make this clear, please?

This is another question that might be marked as a similar question but the answers don't seem to describe what's happening in detail.
[Group by Alias not working -stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312556/alias-for-group-by-clause?rq=1)

Comment: Becasue of the order in which a query is parsed and processed

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for your comment, and I've read the duplicate posts of this but they don't seem to explain why alias in `SELECT` can be called in the `GROUP BY` line. and in MySQL I thought `GROUP BY` is executed first before `SELECT`. So I don't think it makes sense that `GROUP BY` can refer to alias in `SELECT`.